# Getting a SQL Syntax Error Exception, Not sure why?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

I am using the following code snippet below to calculate some range queries on a database. Currently when I run the code, I get the following Error.

```
SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Anyone has any idea what might be causing this? I'm new to Databases specially JDBC, any help will be appreciated.

```
    String mainCity = "Main_City";

    String view_Main_City = "CREATE VIEW "+mainCity+"(City, Phi,Lamda) AS "
            +"SELECT CITY, ((Latitude*3.14)/180), ((Longitude*3.14)/180)"
            +"FROM MAP "
            + "WHERE CITY = " + "'" 
            + args[3]+"'";


    String otherCities = "OtherCities";

    String view_Without_Main_City = "CREATE VIEW "+otherCities+"(City, Phi,Lamda) AS "
            +"SELECT CITY, ((Latitude*3.14)/180), ((Longitude*3.14)/180)"
            +"FROM MAP "
            + "WHERE CITY <> " + "'" 
            + args[3]+"'";


    String HaverViewName = "Haver";

    String Haver = "CREATE VIEW "+ HaverViewName +"(City,hav) AS "
            + "SELECT O.City,(  (SIN((M.PHI - O.PHI)/2) * SIN((M.PHI - O.PHI)/2))+COS(M.PHI)*COS(O.PHI)*(SIN((M.LAMDA - O.LAMDA)/2)*SIN((M.LAMDA - O.LAMDA)/2)) ) "
            + "FROM Main_City M,OtherCities O";


    String Distance_From_Main_City = "Distance_From_Main_City";

    String d_f_m = "CREATE VIEW "+Distance_From_Main_City+"(CITY,Distance) AS "
            + "SELECT O.City , ( 12742 * aTAN2((SQRT(H.HAV)), (SQRT(1-H.HAV))) ) AS d "
            + "FROM OtherCities O JOIN Haver H "
            + "ON O.City = H.City";

    ResultSet m = stmt.executeQuery(view_Main_City);
    ResultSet v = stmt.executeQuery(view_Without_Main_City);
    ResultSet h = stmt.executeQuery(Haver);
    ResultSet d = stmt.executeQuery(d_f_m);


    if(args[2].equals("RANGE_QUERY")){

        String Range_Q = "SELECT CITY, ROUND(Distance,2) AS Distance "
                + "FROM Distance_From_Main_City "
                +"WHERE Distance <" + args[4]
                        + " ORDER BY DISTANCE ASC";

        ResultSet Range_Query_Answer = stmt.executeQuery(Range_Q);

        while(Range_Query_Answer.next()){
            System.out.println(Range_Query_Answer.getString("City") + " " + Range_Query_Answer.getString("Distance"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which specific line of code is producing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that one of the view names which you want to use, is already used by a table or another view. So check for duplicates (also check if existing views are deleted before you run your application a second time).

Answer (score 1):

The views would seem to already exist.

You want to use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` instead of `CREATE VIEW`.  As suggested by the keywords, this will create the view if it doesn't exist and alter it if it does exist.